# Procfile alternative of aws

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services

India heroku we use procfile `release: rake db:migrate`. Is there any alternative in aws? I am new to Amazon web services.

Comment: if you mean elasticbeanstalk it does it for you

Comment: Alternative to running migrations? This question needs more context.